# Invalid HTML code generated by WordPress (<link rel='https://api.w.org/'...)

Tags: wordpress

WordPress 5.2.4

I'm trying to get valid HTML.

A validator (https://validator.w3.org/ ) shows this:

> Error: Bad value https://api.w.org/ for attribute rel on element link:
>   The string https://api.w.org/ is not a registered keyword.
>
> From line 135, column 1; to line 135, column 60
>
> ↩https://api.w.org/' href='http://ved/wp-json/'
>   />↩

The problem seems to be in wp-includes/rest-api.php, line 841:

```
function rest_output_link_wp_head() {
    $api_root = get_rest_url();

    if ( empty( $api_root ) ) {
        return;
    }

    echo "<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='" . esc_url( $api_root ) . "' />\n"; // Line 841.
}
```

Well, this seems to be the core of WordPress. But it renders invalid code.

Cold you help me with these two questions:
1. What is the most correct and elegant way to cope with this problem?
2. Is there anything that should be taken into consdideration here. I mean that I don't seem to be going to use REST API, but maybe some plugins need REST API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Disable REST API link tag
remove_action('wp_head', 'rest_output_link_wp_head', 10);

// Disable oEmbed Discovery Links
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_discovery_links', 10);

// Disable REST API link in HTTP headers
remove_action('template_redirect', 'rest_output_link_header', 11, 0);
```

Try to add above code in function.php

Answer (score 0):

Removing rest_output_link_wp_head() will make your theme invalid in case you would like to submit it to wordpress.org.